# C# unicode characters not getting displayed

Tags: c#, .net, console

i'm trying the msdn example,
using windows xp , .Net 4.0,

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Example
{
   static void Main()
   {
      string unicodeString = "This string contains the unicode character Pi (\u03a0)";

      // Create two different encodings.
      Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
      Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

      // Convert the string into a byte array.
      byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);

      // Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
      byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes);

      // Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string.
      char[] asciiChars = new char[ascii.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)];
      ascii.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0);
      string asciiString = new string(asciiChars);

      // Display the strings created before and after the conversion.
      Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", unicodeString);
      Console.WriteLine("Ascii converted string: {0}", asciiString);
   }
}
```

Expected:

```
// The example displays the following output:
//    Original string: This string contains the unicode character Pi (Π)
//    Ascii converted string: This string contains the unicode character Pi (?)
```

But I'm getting

```
// The example displays the following output:
//    Original string: This string contains the unicode character Pi (?)
//    Ascii converted string: This string contains the unicode character Pi (?)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin it didn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: setting the Console.OutputEncoding may solve the problem

Comment: You may also need to set the console's font to a TrueType one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055659/c-unicode-string-output. For the reason why this is failing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971684/c-console-font/3971750

Comment: Also you need to fix/check HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\Codepage or delete that. For example using ComboFix makes that value ASCII so the unicode chars cannot be seen.

Comment: I'm trying to have a label and print the unicode on that label. In that case what changes you suggest ?

Comment: label1.Text = "This string contains the unicode character Pi (π)"; works fine. You can change label's font if you want a more understandable symbol.

Comment: Has the problem been solved? Give us a feedback please.

Comment: If i try something like label1.Text ="This string contains the unicode character of triangle (◄)"; IT doesnt work.

Comment: It works for me but it's weird. I suggest using Arial (Normal one) font family and it can be done easily in design mode. Also you can set the text on there.

Comment: Yes I worked around by selecting a unicode font.

Comment: The default font Microsoft Sans Serif works too but if you're using another font it may cause that problem.

Comment: Default font doesnt work for me .It works only with Ms sans serif unicode